# How to get the base64 encoded certificate (PEM) from connected ssl session

Tags: c++, c, openssl, certificate, x509

I am using the following to get the PEM certificate for a connected session in openssl C. What I need is to get a base64 encoded certificate.

```
if(this->ssl) {
  X509 *cert = SSL_get_certificate(this->ssl);
  EVP_PKEY *pubKey = X509_get_pubkey(cert);
  LOG_INFO("Public key is " << BN_bn2hex(pubKey->pkey.rsa->n));
}
```

Any information on how can I achieve this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [i2d_X509](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/d2i_X509.html#) function to get DER encoded certificate.
Then use your favorite base64 encoder and encode it to PEM.
Do not forget to add **-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----** and **-----END CERTIFICATE-----** if you want it proper way.

[Here](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/34/howto-base64-encode-with-cc-and-openssl/) you may find example on how to encode with OpenSSL itself.
In using OpenSSL you may simplify things by using **i2d_X509_bio** function to put DER encoded data directly into BIO.